# How to install jmeter on CentOS 6.3 Server

Tags: jmeter

I need to install `jmeter` on `CentOS 6.3` server to do load testing for one of my project. How can I install jmeter on CentOS 6.3 Server?

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the JMeter binary.
2. Unzip apache-jmeter-*.tgz to your preferred location
3. Run bin/jmeter.sh

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://testedandwrote.blogspot.in/2012/09/installing-jmeter-on-centoswill-work-on.html) is the step by step tutorial for installing `jmeter` on `CentOS`.

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the Jmeter binaries and that's it. Be sure to have the java sdk installed and choose the jmeter bin distribution for that JDK version. Check the apache [site](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for more info.

Notice that Jmeter is a visual app and will need that to create and configure the tests.

Also can, after your test is configure you can run those test using command line.

Thanks!

@Leo